# In Google Sheets, is there some way to set a cell's value to 1 if another cell ever had a certain value, even if that value changes later on?

Tags: google-sheets

Lets say I have a sheet where I want B1 to be TRUE if A1 was ever TRUE. Even if I set A1 to false at a later date, I want B1 to stay TRUE if A1 had ever been TRUE. Is this possible?

I was hoping I could do something like this for B1, but it causes a circular dependency:

```
=IF(OR(B1, A1), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

NO. There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151809?pli=1) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable iterative calculation, then circular references are allowed and your formula works in exactly the manner you intend...